# Hover on child nested element should not effect parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML for my page is like this. When I hover over the child, it triggers hover on the parent as well. I want only the child hover to be effective when I hover child.
How can I achieve this? Prefer CSS solution but javascript addition is also fine

```
<div class="element">
  <span class="inv"> invisible1 </span>
  <span class="col1"> test </span>
  <div class="element"> 
    <span class="inv"> invisible2 </span>
    <span class="col2"> test child </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inv{
  opacity: 0;
}
.element:hover > .inv{
  opacity: 100;
}
```

Comment: Try moving the `:hover` to the `.inv` instead of the `.element`, like this: `.element > .inv:hover {`

Comment: and no need opacity:100 ... 1 is enough

Comment: Moving hover to inv (the hidden element!!) will not work, it will simply not trigger, and even if it did that would not trigger when hovering the item itself.

Comment: I used hover over element class as it will be triggered when hovered over both inv and col, also col is not always constant, in can change of different elements

Comment: Does the order of `.inv` and `.col` in the Dom matter in your layout? If they're positioned using CSS, you could put `col` first and use a sibling selector (`+`)

Comment: @Salketer if you hover on an element with opaciy:0 the hover will work because the element exist in the DOM .. it won't work when it's display:none, in this case there is no way to trigger hover on the element itself

Comment: @TemaniAfif you are right, thanks I had it mixed...

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer: You cannot prevent hover to work on parent.

Long answer: The events always bubble up the dom tree unless stopped by javascript, but to CSS, the element will still be hovered on. The reason why is simply because since the child is inside the parent, hovering the child makes it obvious that you are hovering the parent too.

You can, however, change your markup to accommodate for what you would like.

```css
.inv {
  opacity: 0;
}

.item:hover>.inv {
  opacity: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="item">
    <span class="inv"> invisible1 </span>
    <span class="col"> test </span>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="item">
      <span class="inv"> invisible2 </span>
      <span class="col"> test child </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to say the same thing but didn't know how to formulate it, so plus one from me

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hacky solution that allow you to hover on the visible text to show the hidden one. The trick is to extend the hidden text with a pseudo element to capture the hover event.

It's a hacky solution because you need to specify a big value that may cover other elements *(and probably other side effects)*

```css
.inv {
  opacity:0;
  position:relative;
}
.inv:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:-200px; /*this need to be big to cover the visible text*/
}
.inv:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <span class="inv"> invisible1 </span>
  <span class="col1"> test </span>
  <div class="element">
    <span class="inv"> invisible2 </span>
    <span class="col2"> test child </span>
  </div>
</div>
```